# Highcharts x axis date full range even if there is not enough data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I have an highcharts linechart with data. I want to display the data with datetime on the x-axis. This works fine, my only problem is that the x-axis always seems to end at the end of my data.

I want to display the whole year in months, even if there are only 3 months available.

Is there a way to "Force" the x-axis to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to pass any null values - all you have to do is set an axis min and max.

That way, no matter what data you send, the full time span will be displayed.

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.min
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.max

for `example`:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/LeXmz/

Answer (score 1):

Highcharts will only show the last data point that is specified. If you want to force it to show the the whole year ,you will have to pass it all the data points for the those times you want displayed, but for the value pass null.

```
series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6,
               null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 
               null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1),
        pointInterval: 1 * 3600 * 1000 * 24 // one hour
    }]
```

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/cosset777/wZDCq/)

Comment: Adding null values seems like a lot of overkill when you can just set the axis min and max....